# I have some trouble with "grep"and collating symbols

Tags: shell, grep

Here is my problem.A existed file named data.f,I use collating symbol "48",I want to match "48"in my file with Collating symbols in bracket expressions.

```
grep '[[.48.]]' data.f
```

but there is some error tip:

```
grep: Invalid collation character
```

but, there is no problem with character classes in bracket expressions.

```
grep "[[:alpha:]]" data.f
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to grep 48

```
grep 48 file
```

if you want to grep "48"

```
grep '"48"' file
```

// to avoid discussion in comments I extend my post with more examples

if you want to grep n occurrences of "48" in one line you should use regular expressions

```
cat file | grep '\(.*"48"\)\{n\}' | grep -v '\(.*"48"\)\{n+1\}'
```

basically you grep lines with at least n occurrences, and then with invert-match you exclude lines with n+1 occurrences of string, so you get n occurrences

in you comment you mentioned you wanted to grep lines with 5 occurrences of "48", that CAN be separated by other characters (that's the reason I put .* before "48")
so here is the sample

```
cat file | grep '\(.*"48"\)\{5\}' | grep -v '\(.*"48"\)\{6\}'
```

Comment: Also, if you want to grep for 48 only at the beginning of the line use `grep '^48' file`

Comment: to complete previous comment, if you want to match at the end     `grep '48$'`

Comment: eh，what should I do if I wanna match "48" 5 times?

Comment: @znlyj you want to grep it 5 times or 5 lines which contains "48"?

Comment: I mean , in the pattrens. one line contains 5 .

Comment: so you want to grep line which contains 5x "48", that can be separated by other text?

Comment: yes.someone tell me use -F option,that is grep -F '[[.48.]]' data.f,but get no output,why?

Comment: @znlyj to avoid discussion here I've edited this post, or we can move to chat

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't `grep '48' data.f`  work?

Comment: In fact, I wanna know the use of [.48.]

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you mean by “I use collating symbol "48"” (I know what collation classes are, which is what grep expects to see in your input, but I don't know what a collation symbol would be), but from one of your comments, it seems you're actually looking for the exact string `[[.48.]]` in your file. Here's two ways of doing just that:

```
grep -F '[[.48.]]' data.f

grep '\[\[.48.]]' data.f
```

In one of your other comments, you asked for how to ask grep for lines with at least five occurrences of “48” on them. That's a pretty clear regex question:

```
grep -E '(.*48){5}' data.f
```

Comment: I try it,grep -F '[[.48.]]' data.f, but get no output,why?

Comment: Does you source contain the character sequence `[[.48.]]`? If not, then getting no output is the expected result.